# Confused How to Make Sure Data is "Good" in IOStream

Tags: c++, iostream

I am pretty sure I have written the code for the two functions in my class incorrectly.  I am confused how to take in just the two pieces of data correctly (x and y) and make sure they are in a good state.

```
/**
 * Requires: ins is in good state.
 * Modifies: ins, x, y.
 * Effects:  Reads point in form (x,y).
 */
void read(istream& ins);

/**
 * Requires: outs is in good state.
 * Modifies: outs.
 * Effects:  Writes point in form (x,y).
 */
void write(ostream& outs);


void Point::read(istream& ins) {
char junk;
char junk2;
char junk3;
while (cin.good()) {
    cin >> junk >> x >> junk2 >> y >> junk3;
}
}

void Point::write(ostream& outs) {
while (cout.good()) {
    cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")";
}
}
```

Comment: What is `x` and `y`?

Comment: They are the points in a coordinate (x,y).

Comment: Ah ha. You completely enlightened me now. Mind posting a [MCVE] that reproduces your actual problem as required please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [istream's `.bad()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/) function after reading to determine if there was a problem.  "Problems could be Logical error on i/o operation" (failbit) or     "Read/writing error on i/o operation" (badbit).

Below, I've replaced `cin` with `ins`, as you've passed it as an argument and it's clearly meant to be the `istream` object you need to extract from.  I've also added local variables (using an underscore as a prefix), then only copy to `x` and `y` if there was no error.

If an error is detected, you could simply "return", however there would be no indication to your user that a read-error occured and `x`/`y` weren't touched.  As an alternative, I've chosen to throw an exception, but you could also choose to `cout`/`cerr` a message, then return, or choose to return the result (success/fail) instead of using a void return and let the calling function handle the error.

```
void Point::read(istream& ins) {
  char _junk;
  int _x, _y;

  ins >> _junk >> _x >> _junk >> _y >> _junk;

  if (ins.bad()) 
    throw "Error";

  x = _x;  // Assuming x and y are members of class Point
  y = _y;
}
```

For the `Point::write` function, don't bother with the while loop.  Normally I don't check ostream objects, but if you really want to, then just check if `.good()` is true before and after you write.  If you detect a problem, you can handle the error however you like; `return`, `throw` an exception, and/or log the error.